# Manipulating Output from an Array of Nested Hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I've been pulling data from an API in JSON, and am currently stumbling over an elmementary problem

The data is on companies, like Google and Facebook, and is in an array or hashes, like so:

```
[
  {"id"=>"1", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Google", "stock_symbol"=>GOOG, "primary_role"=>"company"}},
  {"id"=>"2", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Facebook", "stock_symbol"=>FB, "primary_role"=>"company"}}
]
```

Below are two operations I'd like to try:

1. For each company, print out the name, ID, and the stock symbol (i.e. "Google - 1 - GOOG" and "Facebook - 2 - FB")
2. Remove "primary role" key/value from Google and Facebook
3. Assign a new "industry" key/value for Google and Facebook

Any ideas?

Am a beginner in Ruby, but running into issues with some functions / methods (e.g. undefined method) for arrays and hashes as this looks to be an array OF hashes

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us help you, it would be great if you could post some example code you've tried, to try to whittle the problem down a bit.

Comment: In addition to explaining the transformation steps, could you show how the result should look like? Are there any other entries beside Google and Facebook? If so, how should those be transformed? (maybe just include a non-industry entry in your example and the corresponding result)

Comment: If you have further things you'd like to achieve, please create new SO questions for each one. That way they can be answered independently, and has the benefit that you end up with extra SO points :)

Answer (score 15):

Ruby provides a couple of tools to help us comprehend arrays, hashes, and nested mixtures of both.

Assuming your data looks like this (I've added quotes around `GOOG` and `FB`):

```
data = [
  {"id"=>"1", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Google", "stock_symbol"=>"GOOG", "primary_role"=>"company"}},
  {"id"=>"2", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Facebook", "stock_symbol"=>"FB", "primary_role"=>"company"}}
]
```

You can iterate over the array using [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each), e.g.:

```
data.each do |result|
   puts result["id"]
end
```

Digging into a hash and printing the result can be done in a couple of ways:

```
data.each do |result|
  # method 1
  puts result["properties"]["name"]

  # method 2  
  puts result.dig("properties", "name")
end
```

Method #1 uses the [`hash[key]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) syntax, and because the first hash value is another hash, it can be chained to get the result you're after. The drawback of this approach is that if you have a missing `properties` key on one of your results, you'll get an error.

Method #2 uses [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig), which accepts the nested keys as arguments (in order). It'll dig down into the nested hashes and pull out the value, but if any step is missing, it will return `nil` which can be a bit safer if you're handling data from an external source

### Removing elements from a hash

Your second question is a little more involved. You've got two options:

1. Remove the `primary_role` keys from the nested hashes, or
2. Create a new object which contains all the data except the `primary_role` keys.

I'd generally go for the latter, and recommend reading up on immutability and immutable data structures.

However, to achieve [1] you can do an in-place [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete) of the key:

```
data.each do |company| 
  company["properties"].delete("primary_role")
end
```

### Adding elements to a hash

You assign new hash values simply with [`hash[key] = value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), so you can set the industry with something like:

```
data.each do |company| 
  company["properties"]["industry"] = "Advertising/Privacy Invasion"
end
```

which would leave you with something like:

```
[
  {
    "id"=>"1", 
    "properties"=>{
      "name"=>"Google", 
      "stock_symbol"=>"GOOG", 
      "industry"=>"Advertising/Privacy Invasion"
    }
  },
  {
    "id"=>"2", 
    "properties"=>{
      "name"=>"Facebook", 
      "stock_symbol"=>"FB", 
      "industry"=>"Advertising/Privacy Invasion"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the first operation, you can iterate through the array of companies and access the relevant information for each company. Here's an example in Ruby:

```
companies = [  {"id"=>"1", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Google", "stock_symbol"=>"GOOG", "primary_role"=>"company"}},  {"id"=>"2", "properties"=>{"name"=>"Facebook", "stock_symbol"=>"FB", "primary_role"=>"company"}}]

companies.each do |company|
  name = company['properties']['name']
  id = company['id']
  stock_symbol = company['properties']['stock_symbol']
  puts "#{name} - #{id} - #{stock_symbol}"
end
```

This will print out the name, ID, and stock symbol for each company.

To remove the "primary role" key/value, you can use the delete method on the properties hash. For example:

```
companies.each do |company|
  company['properties'].delete('primary_role')
end
```

To add a new "industry" key/value, you can use the []= operator to add a new key/value pair to the properties hash. For example:

```
companies.each do |company|
  company['properties']['industry'] = 'Technology'
end
```

This will add a new key/value pair with the key "industry" and the value "Technology" to the properties hash for each company.